# a strange placing m numbers between the two m permutation problem

Tags: number-theory, permutations

For some positive integers n it is possible to rearrange the sequence $1,2,3, ... , n$, $1,2,3, ... , n$ so that for
each $m = 1,2, ... n $ there are exactly $m$ other terms between the two copies of m. For $n = 3$, an
example is $3,1,2,1,3,2$. For $n = 4$, an example is $4,1,3,1,2,4,3,2.$ On the other hand, this cannot be done
for $n = 5.$ Determine with proof whether such a rearrangement exists for $n = 2018.$

What I have tried is to “build up" from cases: I discovered that n=2 is impossible but I can't get anywhere from building up. Then I tried a "space taking" argument-- because there are $m$ other terms between two copies of $m$, I tried to add up$1+2+3+...n$= $n(n+1)/2$ but I discovered that the space taken up could be shared... Some suggestion of how to solve this will be appreciated.

Comment: HINT Think parity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

If you add up the distances between the pairs of identical numbers in the original sequence, you get $n\cdot (n-1)$. Now, as you shuffle the elements around, what will happen to the parity of that? And how does that compare to the parity of the sum of distances in the goal sequence (which is indeed $\frac{n(n+1)}{2})$?

Comment: Um sorry I don't get this-- so shuffling elements will only decrease $n(n-1)$ by 2 as the distance when moving element causes at least two element to "respond"?

Comment: @Guywhofailedeverything Well, if you take $n=5$ you find that in the original sequence the sum of distances is $5\cdot 4=20$, which is even (come to think of it, $n\cdot (n-1)$ will of course *always* be even, but $\frac{5\cdot6}{2}=15$ which is odd, and notice that as you keep swapping any two elements, the parity always stays the same, since for each element that you swap you either inease or decrease the distance by $1$. So, this is why it is impossible for $n=5$ and indeed for any $n$ for which $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ is odd. Unfortunately, for $n=2018$ it is even ...

Comment: I don't quite get the idea why the sum of original sequence is n*(n-1) but I understand what you mean on rest of the thing... can you kindly expand on why it is n(n-1)...

Comment: @Guywhofailedeverything In the original you have all numbers except for $n$ itself between any $n$ and $n$, so that's $n-1$ distance for each $n$, giving a total distance of $n(n-1)$

Comment: @Guywhofailedeverything Oh!  Just realized: this parity argument *does* work! BRain fart! I thought $2018$ divided by $2$ was even, but it is not. OK, so that means $\frac{2018\cdot 2019}{2}$ is odd, and so we know the goal sequence is impossible for $n=2018$.